# Get Camera Roll Photos without UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I was wondering how one can get the photos off of iPhone's camera roll / photo library without opening up a UIImagePickerController. I've been trying to Google this but it always points me to the `UIImagePickerController` which I'm reluctant to use since it will open up another view controller. I know this is possible since Facebook Messenger has this feature. It presents my camera photo options without opening up iPhone's native photo app. For reference this is the `UIImagePickerController`

[image: UIImagePickerController]

and this is the Facebook Messenger App

[image: Facebook Messenger]

Comment: You have to use the `AssetsLibrary` framework: `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` Here is a good link as well: http://codemastergabriel.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/access-mediaphotosvideos-using-alassetslibrary-iosobjective-c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my comment suggested:

You have to use the `AssetsLibrary` framework: `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` Here is a good link as well to help you get started: http://codemastergabriel.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/access-mediaphotosvideos-using-alassetslibrary-iosobjective-c/

Comment: I was hoping to find the name of the controller that is used to make this work. Like you, I have been searching for a solution to this, but haven't been able to find the controllers name. I thought it was something along the lines of UIActionView, but clearly that is wrong.